# auto scroll to fixed column datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a datagrid control in my winform application. It has nearly 30 columns. First 2 column are frozen and others can be views using scrollbars.

Its working fine.

I would like to add some functionality on it by allowing user to select a column from column list above and making the datagrid scroll to that column automatically.

So i would like to ask how could i make my datagrid to scroll to specified column automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got nice answer on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx

ie. can be done using `"DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = x"`

thnx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

just put like this:

```
DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = DataGridView.Columns.count -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answers - If you name your columns then you can do this:

```
dgvContacts.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = colSurname.Index
```